# Creating a percentile graph/chart with generated percentile values

Tags: excel

How do i create a percentile graph given that i already have my percentile values for each percentile namely 10%, 20%, 30% ...... 100% ? Example attached below. Wanna create sort of a bellcurve to see and compare

[image]

Comment: Did you Try the Line Chart ? With Percentages on X-Axis and Values on Y-Axis ?

Comment: select the first 2 rows, then press F11. Choose chart and change/swap data source as needed. || If successful, save the chart and reproduce it.